# How to use export type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I used a library from NPM

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml
```

and this his the @types/yaml

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yaml
```

In my source code I did import to

```
import * as yaml from 'yaml';
```

but I don't have access to YAMLError 
it is define in the @types/yaml

```
export type YAMLError =
    | YAMLSyntaxError
    | YAMLSemanticError
    | YAMLReferenceError;


https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/yaml/index.d.ts
```

Can I use export type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current situation, you would need to use `yaml.YAMLError` as you've namespaced your import.

You could do:

```
import { YAMLError } from 'yaml'
```

It "should" automatically retrieve the correct type information for you.

Depending on your editor or IDE, it can do automatic imports for you if you have the right plugins like the TypeScript Language Server.

`export type` is to make your new `type` available to the rest of your code and be able to import it. If you were to make an addition to the existing type or a completely new one based of it like this example:

```
export type MyYAMLError = YAMLError | null
```

You could start using `MyYAMLERROR` in your own code. Not sure if this is what you're looking for so I suggest redoing your imports as described above.